# Accessing PyMongo UpdateOne operation properties

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

If I am receiving a list of prepared PyMongo UpdateOne operations (e.g. below)...

```
print(type(to_load[0]))
> <class 'pymongo.operations.UpdateOne'>

print(to_load[0])
> UpdateOne({'id': XXX}, {'$set': {'name': 'YYY'}}, True, None, None, None)
```

...is it possible to then extract information from these? For instance, if I want to get a list of all of the affected `'id'` values `[XXX, ...]`, is there something like the below (which does not work) that will work?

```
for record in to_load:
  print(record['filter'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it with the `_filter` attribute, with the usual caveat that `_` prefixed attributes are protected and subject to change without notice.

```
for record in to_load:
    print(record._filter)
```

Reference: examining the source code.